# import wikipedia article using wget or curl (on windows)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, mediawiki, wget, wikipedia

i have a folder with wikipedia article (XML format).

I want imported files throught the Webinterface (Special:Import). Currently i do it with imacro. But this often hangs and need a lot of resources (Memory) an can only processing one file at once.So i am looking for better solution.

I currently figured out, that in have to login to get an edittoken. This is needed to upload the file.

Read already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979630/what-is-the-wget-command-to-submit-data-to-this-form). get stuck
To get his run in need two wget/curl "commandlines"

1. to login and get the edittoken (push user and pwd to form, get edittoken)
2. push the file to the Formular (push edittoken and content to form)
3. Building the loop to processing more than one file, i can do by my own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send a header using a HTTP request through a curl call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call)

Comment: yes and no, it is only a solution for the second Problem but how get i the edittoken and post it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's be clear: the web interface is not the right way to do this. MediaWiki installation requirements include shell access to the server, which would allow you to use importDump.php as needed for heavier imports.

Second, if you want to import a Wikipedia article from the web interface then you shouldn't be downloading the XML directly: Special:Import can do that for you. Set

```
$wgImportSources = array( 'wikipedia' );
```

or whatever ([see manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgImportSources)), visit Special:Import, select Wikipedia from the dropdown, enter the title to import, confirm.

Third, if you want to use the commandline then why not use the MediaWiki web API, also available with [plenty of clients](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code). Most clients handle tokens for you.

Finally, if you really insist on using wget/curl over index.php, you can get a token visiting `api.php?action=query&meta=tokens` in your browser (check on api.php for the exact instructions for your MediaWiki version) and then do something like

```
curl -d "&action=submit&...@filename.xml" .../index.php?title=Special:Import
```

(intentionally partial code so that you don't run it without knowing what you're doing).

Comment: Where could OP obtain API tokens?

Comment: api.php?action=query&meta=tokens; but the exact URL varies across MediaWiki releases depending on action (it's still evolving in 1.25alpha). With (3), no need to worry about tokens.

Comment: Great. Can you include that in your answer please?